# Rails does not throw UnknownAction error when :except/:only options are used in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a route configuration as follows:

```
map.resources :users, :only => [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
```

When a user tries to access the page `http://localhost/users` rails should throw an error. I was expecting rails to throw `ActionController::UnknownAction` error.

To my surprise, Rails threw `ActionController::MethodNotAllowed` error. Similar behavior  is seen when `:except` is used in route configuration.

I am relying on `ActionController::UnknownAction` to display a custom 404 page. In the above scenario I end up displaying a server error page.

The problem can be addressed by removing the `:except/:only` from routes.I am wondering if there is an elegant solution that can work with `:except/:only` options.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `http://localhost/users` URL is available on POST for the `create` action. So, the action exists, but the method is not OK.